# Render email message to component in React

Tags: css, reactjs, email

Is there a way to render email message that is in String format in React component?

Any package I can use? Any way without package?

I have variable holding the email message in String format. What I am able to do is use DangerousSetInnerHTML to render this message in the page. The problem here is, my layout (CSS) of my website is changing whenever I render the email message. I believe, the cause of this is the css styling in the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution if the CSS is the problem is to render the email in a `iframe`. This will make sure there is a clear separation between your code and the email code.

Here is a example on codepen to display HTML in an iframe with React: https://codepen.io/micha149/pen/zBzLwJ?editors=0010